# Aggregate prices and volume hourly pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I need quick help. how can I resample data in this data frame from 1min candles to 1 hour
i don't want to sum the price maybe choose the highest or lowest, only the volume column I need to sum. 
this is the dataframe in csv https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yTd0TB6Pp9obg4iyCWzeFIg3lin9tYVc/view?usp=sharing
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('BTC.csv')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df = df.resample('1H').agg({'Close': 'min', 'Volume': 'sum'})
print(df)

                       Close  Volume
Date
2020-06-06 15:00:00  9650.39   201.0
2020-06-06 16:00:00  9593.09  1616.0
2020-06-06 17:00:00  9595.00  1140.0
2020-06-06 18:00:00  9606.57   642.0
2020-06-06 19:00:00  9614.44  1015.0
2020-06-06 20:00:00  9647.68  1293.0
2020-06-06 21:00:00  9678.52  1293.0
2020-06-06 22:00:00  9635.49  1021.0
2020-06-06 23:00:00  9644.18  1118.0
2020-06-07 00:00:00  9629.88   801.0
2020-06-07 01:00:00  9647.38   541.0
2020-06-07 02:00:00  9654.82  1034.0
2020-06-07 03:00:00  9671.70   710.0
2020-06-07 04:00:00  9677.98  1264.0
2020-06-07 05:00:00  9659.31   798.0
2020-06-07 06:00:00  9656.76   886.0
2020-06-07 07:00:00  9639.48  1769.0
2020-06-07 08:00:00  9599.25  3190.0
2020-06-07 09:00:00  9623.41  1332.0
2020-06-07 10:00:00  9610.64  1018.0
2020-06-07 11:00:00  9575.59  1812.0
2020-06-07 12:00:00  9499.99  5431.0
2020-06-07 13:00:00  9446.98  4372.0
2020-06-07 14:00:00  9426.07  5999.0
2020-06-07 15:00:00  9463.05  1097.0
```

Comment: close shouldn't be min but last?